# Which Ubuntu version will suit my computer

Tags: system-installation

My computer Configuration
Pentium D102GGC2 2.80 GHz
2GB Ram
1TB Hard disk
Ati radeon xpress 200 Plz suggest which ubuntu version will good for me

Answer (score 0):

With your setup, I would recommend that you use and install [Xubuntu 12.04](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/), for the extended support.  Also Xubuntu requirements are not as demanding as other distros.